# finding strcutural holes constraint , efficiency,ego density and effective size in r

Tags: r

I am working on the adjacency matrix to find the results of the `egonet` package function. But when I run the command `index.egonet`, it gives me an error.

My adjacency matrix "p2":

```
 p2
  1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 6
1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
2 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0
3 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1
4 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
5 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
7 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
8 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
9 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
6 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I apply this command on the adjacency for the desired results but it gives me an error

```
index.egonet(p2)
```

> `Error in dati[ego.name, y] : subscript out of bounds`

So any alternative or solution to current code error will highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ego name must be "EGO" in capital letters, as far as I could understand from working with that function.

colnames(p2) <- rownames(p2) <- c("EGO", 2:ncol(p2))
index.egonet(p2)

this should work...